# Get value of select2 when using input type text in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am using multiple `select2` on my page to send mail to users. One for `To` users and second for `CC` users. I am using both fields as input. I want that When I select any user in the `TO` field It should not display in `CC` field. The user list is displayed using ajax. So I need to send all users in ajax from to fields. I am using

```
var toUser=$("#to_user").select2('data');
```

But I am not getting the users records. What should I use to get all users which are selected in the `To` field? MY field is like

```
<input type="text" id="to_users" name="toUsersData"/>
```

Comment: have you tried var `toUser=$("#to_user").val();` ??

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had found it in google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myval=$('#to_users').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
var toUser = $("#to_user").val();
```